Email Template Body is null
I am trying to query the custom html template and use it in apex. But the body is coming as blank. Any reason why the Body is returning null.
EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Name, Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name ='xxxxx'];
system.debug('Email Template**'+et);
List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
toAddress.add('email@nomail.com');        
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
mail.setSubject(et.subject);
mail.setHTMLBody(et.Body);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
allmsg.add(mail);
Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);


You need to [edit] your post to include more details.  In your debug statement, do you see a value in et.body?  When you receive the email, is everything else correct except for the body?

Debug statement - EmailTemplate: {Id=00Xxxxx, Subject='Test Rate Exception, Body=null}. Receiving the email with blank email body.   The template(custom html) was working if we use it in other modes like auto-response rules but when I try to query it not pulling the body.

This is likely caused by the fact that there is no Text Version created for the Email Template. The HTML and Text versions are stored in different fields on the EmailTemplate record, Body (for Text Version) and HTMLValue (for the HTML version).
To utilise the HTML version of the Email Template, you should modify your query to also retrieve the HTMLValue field and use this when using mail.setHTMLBody. If you are doing this, you should use mail.setPlainTextBody(et.Body) to ensure that the email client has this to fallback on if it can't render the HTML version.
It is also worth noting though, that you shouldn't set both the Template ID, and the Body & Subject. According to the Docs for the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.setHTMLBody method:

Optional. The HTML version of the email, specified by the sender. The value is encoded according to the specification associated with the organization. Specify a value for setTemplateId, setHtmlBody, or setPlainTextBody. Or, you can define both setHtmlBody and setPlainTextBody.


update the logic to include the HTMLValue in the query and updated the template with plan text body but only received the text version  to the email not html content.

Did you use the HTMLValue to set the HTML body, or just the Body?

we should not set any body or subject if we set the template.  It worked if I don't set both.

Makes sense, I have updated my answer to reflect that.
